# how to bypass postgresql.conf

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-22.04, postgres-12

I have a database that can not be started. It started when I change `max_wal_size < wal_segement_size`. The error is `FATAL ERROR "max wal sender must be at least twice wal_segment_size"`

I have changed the value back to its original size, but the error still comes up. it seems that the postgres is still having hang over or something is stuck within the "internal cache".

Why postgres does not pick up the new config file ?

How can I clear the "cache" ?

How can I overwrite the postgres.conf during start ? this is mainly to bypass whatever the postgres.conf that postgres read.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That error message does not exist in PostgreSQL.

Perhaps you mean

```
"min_wal_size" must be at least twice "wal_segment_size"
```

If my guess is correct, and you didn't change the WAL segment size from the default 16MB, you can fix the problem by changing `min_wal_size` to a value of at least 32MB.

`max_wal_size` must be no less than `min_wal_size`. Typically, it should be much bigger for decent performance.

Comment: yes @LaurenzAlbe, I meant FATAL `ERROR "max_wal_size must be at least twice wal_segment_size"`